# How to position an element under the cursor if its parent has "margin: 0 auto"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm building a simple draggable functionality:

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="i-plane">
    <div
      id="i-interact"
      v-bind:style="position"
      v-on:mousedown="handleDown"
      v-on:mousemove="handleMove"
      v-on:mouseout="handleUp">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    field: {
      x: 200,
      y: 200
    },
    dragging: false
  },
  computed: {
    position: function() {
      return 'transform: translate(' + this.field.x + 'px,' + this.field.y + 'px)'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleUp: function(e) {
      this.dragging = false
    },
    handleDown: function(e) {
      this.dragging = true
    },
    handleMove: function(e) {
      if (this.dragging) {
        this.field.x = e.clientX
        this.field.y = e.clientY
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>

<style>
#i-plane {
  background: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

#i-interact {
  background: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
</style>
```

If you click `#i-interact` the element is not positioned under the cursor but it flies to the right.

How to modify the code so `#i-interact` moves under the cursor?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/XNLNvM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. First, since you're using `translate` to move the element, you'll need to know its relative position. So, rather than specifying the position on the screen where the mouse is when it's moving, you'll have to specify how many pixels the mouse has moved relative to where it started on mouse down. (The other alternative would be to position the element absolutely, but I'm assuming you want to stick with `translate`.)

The other issue is that your mouse handlers are all listening to events on the element that you're moving. This will result in very unreliable behavior because if, for example, you move your mouse outside of the element by moving the mouse quickly, your movements will no longer be tracked.

See [my fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRogzJ) of your CodePen. I have added an object to know the originating `start` coordinates and I've made the mouse event listeners document-wide and moved them into `created()`:

```
created() {
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleDown)
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleUp)
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMove)
},
```

This works well enough in your specific example, but it is still not *perfect* because the `start` position is based on where you originally click into the element to move it, and also you may just want the mouse events tracked within a given container. To make it better you could upon `mouseup` actually move the element to the new position and reset the `translate` to zero, then on the next `mousedown` you could set the new `start` position.

As there are a lot of possible routes you could take here and I don't want to just guess at what your requirements are, so I'm providing just a basic working version of your example. Hopefully it suits your needs sufficiently!

Comment: Thanks it works! The only issue is, when the default cx and xy is, say, 200. The drag messes up.

Comment: That's part of the reason I named them `cx` and `cy`, to denote they're strictly the x and y distance *traveled* by mouse rather than default positioning. What you'd want to do to change the `#i-interact` style as follows to set the default position to 200x200: `position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 200px;`